# Parse Xcode subclass PFQueryTableViewController SIGABRT on push

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, sigabrt

I solved my problem with #import  and now i encountered another problem.

So i need my app to have PFQueryTableViewController. Now.

Storyboard:

I have mainmenuViewController with several buttons. I wanted one to send me to UITableViewController. So i just link(ctrl+drag) button on mainmenuViewController to new UITableViewController. Everything works fine and push occurs.

Now when i subclass UITableViewController to my new file(subclass PFQueryTableViewController) my app suddenly throws SIGABRT whenever i click on linked button.

I have no idea why it happens. I watched several tutorial videos and it seems like people there don't do anything more than just - create UITableViewController, subclass it to PFQueryTableViewController and link button from another view to UITableViewController.

However when i follow these steps SIGABRT comes up and crashes my app.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Can you show the code you use? Or the exception on the console?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/T1Q3leS.jpg

so this is what it throws at me. It refers to EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION 138

Comment: Put a breakpoint on exceptions. That will show you the offending line.

Comment: When i continue to debug it all runs to this: http://i.imgur.com/Ok4h9Vl.png

Comment: Alright so from my NSLog i got this:
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You need to specify a parseClassName for the PFQueryTableViewController.'
anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys i think i finally fixed this. Well as most would say - there is nothing worse than being lazy in coding. I was too lazy to read whole documentation of Parse and there ya go. I beg you for forgiveness.

For anyone having this problem : read https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses PFQueryTableViewController section.

Parse has awesome documentation - better than most frameworks.

From now on i say NO to laziness!